# PHP code not showing anything

Tags: php

This code is supposed to show the number of rows in the column "id". Why isn’t is working, when I go to the page it shows nothing except my HTML stuff?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("quollcraft.net", "quollcr1_forum", "password");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("quollcr1_hub", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo '<p>' . $row ['id'] . ' total users<p>';

    echo "</td>";

    }
echo "</table>";    

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What, exactly, does it produce?

Comment: Use mysql_error() to check if query is correct.

Comment: mysql is deprecated use other extension like mysqli or pdo

Comment: You're putting a lot of trust in your browser too. Add at least one table row in your html table, close the center and p tags. Also if you want the number of rows in the column ID, you may want to use COUNT(id) in your query. That will produce a single row, not all the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Your table name you are using are just table. I guess it should be changed to the real table name from which you want your data

Answer (score 2):

`table` is one of the [`reserved word(s)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to wrap them using backticks.

Like this..

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
                                      ^     ^  //<---- Like that
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 1):

Others have decent MySQL tips, but what happens when you view the source code? Because the HTML seems to be broken at best. This is the cleaned up version based on what I am seeing.:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<center>";
    echo '<p>' . $row ['id'] . ' total users<p>';
    echo "</center>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

You were missing the table row tags `<tr>` & `</tr>` as well as the closing `</center>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to retrieve the total count of `ID`(users) but you missed out the keyword count. You can modify either the `query` or you can get the count of `$result`. Hope this helps.